# Haar measure of the zero set of a nonconstant analytic function on a connected Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group equipped with its unique real analytic structure, $f : G \to \mathbb{R}$ a nonconstant real analytic function on $G$. Is the closed set $Z_f = f^{-1}(0)$ always of Haar measure zero?

[This paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2036518) by John E. Coury  seems relevant. I have a hunch that there should be a simple proof to answer this question in the affirmative, and I would be surprised if this is not true.

Comment: Stated in Bourbaki ([1971](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=43:6834), [10.1.3b](//books.google.com/books?id=bHIz7KNeuNIC&ots=85CgnZoIMt&pg=RA1-PA37)) (+ relevant facts in their Intégration). If $Z_f$ had positive measure, then its image under some analytic chart would have positive Lebesgue measure, [which it can’t](//math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322858/zeros-of-analytic-function-of-several-real-variables).